# Hawking temperature for an asymptotically $\text{AdS}_5$ black hole with a constant magnetic field

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, magnetic-fields, hawking-radiation, wick-rotation

I'm trying to calculate the Hawking temperature for an asymptotically $\text{AdS}_5$ black hole with a constant magnetic field. Suppose that the metric and magnetic field of this background are given by

\begin{align}
\text{d} s^2 &= \frac{L^2}{U(r)} \text{d} r^2 + \frac{1}{L^2} (-U(r) \text{d} t^2 + V(r) (\text{d} x^2 + \text{d} y^2) + W(r) \text{d} z^2) \tag{1},\\
F &= B \text{d} x \wedge \text{d} y,
\end{align}

such that $U(r), V(r), W(r) \rightarrow r^2$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$, and $U(r_h) = 0$, where $r_h$ is the horizon radius. If we expand at $r = r_h$ , the metric functions are approximately

\begin{align}
U(r) &\simeq U_{1, h} (r - r_h),\\
V(r) &\simeq V_{0, h},\\
W(r) &\simeq W_{0, h},
\end{align}

where $U_{1, h}, \ V_{0, h}, \ W_{0, h}$, are expansion coefficients. Plugging these expansions in the metric, and after a Wick rotation, $\text{d} s^2$ becomes

$$\text{d} s^2 \simeq \frac{L^2}{U_{1, h} (r - r_h)} \text{d} r^2 + \frac{1}{L^2} (U_{1, h} (r - r_h) \text{d} t_{\text{E}}^2 + V_{0, h} (\text{d} x^2 + \text{d} y^2) + W_{0, h} \text{d} z^2).$$

Through the change of coordinates

\begin{align}
\rho^2 &= \frac{4L^2 (r - r_h)}{U_{1, h}},\\
\varphi &= \frac{U_{1, h} t_{\text{E}}}{2L^2},
\end{align}

the metric is

$$\text{d} s^2 = \text{d} \rho^2 + \rho^2 \text{d} \varphi^2 + \frac{1}{L^2} (V_{0, h} (\text{d} x^2 + \text{d} y^2) + W_{0, h} \text{d} z^2) \tag{2}.$$

In order to avoid a conic singularity as $\rho \rightarrow 0$, $\varphi$ has to have a period of $2 \pi$. On the other hand, when a Wick rotation is made, the Euclidean time coordinate is identified with period $\beta = \frac{1}{T}$. Therefore the Hawking temperature is given by

$$T_{\text{H}} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{U_{1, h}}{4 \pi L^2}.$$

However, the reason I doubt this result is because, as far as I understand, the metric has to be of the form

$$\text{d} s^2 = U(r) \text{d} t_{\text{E}}^2 + \frac{1}{U(r)} \text{d} r^2 + r^2 \text{d} \Omega_{n - 2}^2 \tag{3},$$

in order to arrive at the afore mentioned conclusion.  Unless I'm mistaken, there's no change of coordinates in which (1) can be transformed into (3).

My question is whether the metric has to be transformed into something analogous to (3) in order to calculate the Hawking temperature, or if it is enough to find a change of coordinates of $(t, r)$ into polar coordinates $(\rho, \varphi)$ and demand the metric to be regular as $r \rightarrow r_h$ (or as $\rho \rightarrow 0$) as shown in (2)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What the background metric is supposed to be (without the black hole, but with magnetic field)? AdS-Melvin or something else?

Comment: I don't know. The reason is that, in principle, I'm studying a magnetized $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM plasma, which because of the AdS/CFT correspondence, is dual to the geometric background I described in my post. It is similar to the background shown here (https://inspirehep.net/literature/829563), or here (https://inspirehep.net/literature/2040463).

Comment: Yes, your equation (3) is incompatible with your metric ansatz. But D'Hoker & Kraus metric is a *black brane* with the near horizon behavior of BTZ $\times T^2$, so in (3)  the part $d\Omega^2_{n-2}$ should become  $d\theta^2$ and add $\text{Const}\cdot (dx^2+dy^2)$.

Comment: Understood. However, unless I'm mistaken, I think there's no need for the metric to be of the form (3) in order to conclude that the Hawking temperature is what I wrote, right? Because all that matters is for the metric to be regular as $r \rightarrow r_h$, and that only intervenes in the $g_{tt}$ and $g_{rr}$ metric components. In fact, this is the same temperature that the second article I linked in my previous comment uses. Thank you for your comments by the way.

Comment: *there's no need for the metric to be of the form (3)* … Right.